# F# "do" statements as Block expressions

Tags: f#, dispose

The [F# spec](http://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/) describes in *10.2.5 `do` statements in Modules*, that on the module level a `do` statement may have attributes, and it will produce a warning, when the type of its expression does not evaluate to `unit`. Apparently, the behaviour of a `do` statement in other positions is akin to a Block expression (*6.5.1*), either a parenthesized or a begin-end-block, while still asserting the `unit` type.

This makes the `do` statement suitable for controlling the scope of Deterministic disposal expressions (*6.6.4*):

```
let d x =
    printf "new %s, " x
    { new System.IDisposable with
        member __.Dispose() = printf "disposing %s, " x }

let ab() =
    use a = d "a"
    use b = d "b"
    printf "a + b, "
ab(); printfn ""
// prints 'new a, new b, a + b, disposing b, disposing a, '

let aba() =
    use a = d "a"
    do  use b = d "b"
        printf "a + b, "
    printf "a, "
aba(); printfn ""
// prints 'new a, new b, a + b, disposing b, a, disposing a, '
```

If it is not explicitly in the spec, is there anything else that keeps the maintainers of the F# compiler from breaking this usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the `aba` function in your example is actually using both a `do` statement and a block expression. The syntax of `do` is `do <expr>` so the body of the `do` statement is a single expression. If we write the same thing with parentheses:

```
let aba() =
  use a = d "a"
  do ( use b = d "b"
       printf "a + b, " )
  printf "a, "
```

The deterministic disposal behaviour then follows from the usual deterministic disposal behaviour of a block expression - rather than from some undocumented property of `do` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need the `do` statement at all here, and using parentheses will be enough:

```
let aba() =
    use a = d "a"
    (
        use b = d "b"
        printf "a + b, "
    )
    printf "a, "
aba(); printfn ""
// Prints "new a, new b, a + b, disposing b, a, disposing a, "
```

This is Tomas Petricek's example minus the `do`. The parentheses define a new scope for the code block they contain, so when you reach the closing parenthesis, `b` goes out of scope and is disposed. To prove that the scoping rules work like this, let's add another variable definition:

```
let aba() =
    use a = d "a"
    (
        use b = d "b"
        let c = 5
        printf "a + b, and c=%d " c  // This compiles
    )
    printf "and now c=%d " c  // This does not compile
    printf "a, "
aba(); printfn ""
```

The first usage of `c`, inside the parentheses, will compile. The second use of `c`, outside the parentheses, will not compile since `c` is out of scope at that point, and you'll get:

> error FS0039: The value or constructor 'c' is not defined.

So if you're using the `do` expression for the sake of controlling when the `IDisposable` goes out of scope, you can achieve the same result with parentheses alone. Up to you which form you find more readable.